# A question from past IB paper - Students and 3 Rows of Desks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I encounter this question from an IB past paper.   I got different answer than the official one.   I wonder if the official one is WRONG and mine is RIGHT.

"A room has nine desks arranged in three rows of three desks. Three students sit in the room. If the students randomly choose a desk find the probability that two out of the front three desks are chosen.
"

Anyone can help give me his/her answer?

Regards
Alex

Comment: Do you know what the official answer is?

Comment: Yes.   But I wonder why mine is different.

Comment: You should show some of your [own work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) first. Could you show us how you got your answer, for example?

Answer (score 0):

$n(S)=3!.{9 \choose 3}$  and.  $n(E)={3 \choose 2}{6 \choose 1}.3!$
$$P(E)=\frac{3×6×6}{9×8×7}=\frac{3}{14}$$

Comment: Why the 3! ?  -- That is my question.

Comment: Without the $3!$ you are assuming that the students have to sit in a certain order: the first student has X options, the second student has Y options, and the third student has Z options. Multiplying by $3! = 3 \times 2 \times 1$ gives the first student three ways to choose their position, the second student two ways to choose their position, and the last student one way.

Comment: Objects are distinct and need to be arranged at distinct places. Hence 3!.

Comment: @Rajan $n(E)$ should be ${3 \choose 2} \times 2 \times 6 \times 3!$ because the students are distinguishable when you choose the $3$ seats in one of the rows.

Comment: I was on the road and I just figured out my mistake.    I argued that the first student selected a front row seat, the probability is 3/9, then the second selected another front-row seat, the probability 2/8, and then the 3rd one selected any seat in last 2 rows, i.e. probability 6/7.   However, I missed to count the cases that the first student can select a back row seat, or the 2nd or the 3rd can select the back row seat.  Thus the probability I calculated earlier, should times 3 cases - 1st student selects back row seat & 2nd student selects back row seat & 3rd student selects back row seat

Comment: , i.e.  times 3.   When one student has selected a back row seat, that other 2 must select the front row seats.   Thus (3/9)(2/8)(6/7) should times 3 to get the final probability.   Right???

Comment: @Toby Mark why multiplying by 2 if multiplying by 3!. Just check I feel what I have done is correct i.e 1st select 2 seats in 1st row and then 1 seat from rest 6 now arrange 3 person on 3 selected seats that's why I considered only ${3 \choose 2}.{6 \choose 1}.3!$

Answer (score 0):

I was on the road and I just figured out my mistake. I argued that the first student selected a front row seat, the probability is 3/9, then the second selected another front-row seat, the probability 2/8, and then the 3rd one selected any seat in last 2 rows, i.e. probability 6/7. However, I missed to count the cases that the first student can select a back row seat, or the 2nd or the 3rd can select the back row seat. Thus the probability I calculated earlier, should times 3 cases - 1st student selects back row seat & 2nd student selects back row seat & 3rd student selects back row seat, i.e. times 3. When one student has selected a back row seat, that other 2 must select the front row seats. Thus (3/9)(2/8)(6/7) should times 3 to get the final probability.

Comment: Actually, this question is from an old "specimen" IB Math paper.   The official answer is:



$$Probability = \frac { C_2^3 \cdot C_1^6  }{ C_3^9}$$

$$ = \frac {3 \cdot 6 \cdot 3! \cdot 6!} {9!} $$

$$ = \frac {3 \cdot 6 \cdot 6}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} = \frac {3}{14} $$

Comment: which, is, another way of thinking, than mine and those of all you guys.

Answer (score 0):

What matters here is which desks are occupied.

There are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to select three desks for the students to occupy.

For the favorable cases, we must select exactly two of the three desks in the front row and one of the remaining six desks in the room, which can be done in $\binom{3}{2}\binom{6}{1}$ ways.

Hence, the probability that exactly two of the three desks in the front row are chosen when students randomly select three of the nine desks in a room with three rows of three desks is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{6}{1}}{\dbinom{9}{3}}$$